I cannot generate new sitemap on my wordpress website
So i bought a already used domain and created a Wordpress website on it. After the completion of the website I generated the sitemap using a plugin (rankmath as well as yoat) but its not generating a new sitemap. Its showing me some custom generated sitemp for my site with 700 URLs while my website has currently 28 pages to the max.
I have contacted hosting and even they did not give a proper solution.
what should I do with this?
To my surprise, if I set the permalinks option in Wordpress to Plain, it gives me correct sitemap, but if set it to /post_name its gives the same error.
